# Regex to replace ' (single quote once) but not '' (single quote twice) with '||'''

Tags: java, regex

In below line if we have single quote (') then we have to replace it with '||''' but if we have single quote twice ('') then it should be as it is.

I tried below piece of code which is not giving me proper output.

**Code Snippet:**

```
static String replaceSingleQuoteOnly = "('(?!')'{0})";
String line2 = "Your Form xyz doesn't show the same child''s name as the name in your account with us.";
System.out.println(line2.replaceAll(replaceSingleQuoteOnly, "'||'''"));
```

**Actual Output by above code:**

```
Your Form xyz doesn'||'''t show the same child''||'''s name as the name in your account with us.
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Your Form xyz doesn'||'''t show the same child''s name as the name in your account with us.
```

> Regular expression is replacing ***child''s*** with ***child''||'''s***. ***child''s***
>   should remain as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a negative look behind  to assure that there is no `'` character before another `'` and remove extra capturing group `()`

so use `(?<!')'(?!')`

```
    String replaceSingleQuoteOnly = "(?<!')'(?!')";
    String line2 = "Your Form xyz doesn't show the same child''s name as the name in your account with us.";
    System.out.println(line2.replaceAll(replaceSingleQuoteOnly, "'||'''"));
```

Output :

```
Your Form xyz doesn'||'''t show the same child''s name as the name in your account with us.
```

---

As per `Apostrophe` usage you can simply use [`(?i)(?<=[a-z])'(?=[a-z])`](https://regex101.com/r/dxexXp/1) to find `'` surrounded by alphabets

```
    String replaceSingleQuoteOnly = "(?i)(?<=[a-z])'(?=[a-z])";
    String line2 = "Your Form xyz doesN'T show the same child''s name as the name in your account with us.";
    System.out.println(line2.replaceAll(replaceSingleQuoteOnly, "'||'''"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) for this, e.g.:

```
String replaceSingleQuoteOnly = "(?<!')'(?!')";
String line2 = "Your Form xyz doesn't show the same child''s name as the name in your account with us.";
System.out.println(line2.replaceAll(replaceSingleQuoteOnly, "'||'''"));
```

Comment: Thanks Darshan for the solution. I still have some issues with regular expression in my code which I have posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/42935679/3525348
Could you please help me on it.